# Remove non ASCII characters in string in pig latin

Tags: apache-pig

How to remove non ASCII characters from string in pig latin with out using UDF?

A℅♂♀¶】【◆©℃°b sting
Ab sting

Answer (score 1):

You have to create udf like this

```
package pig.udfs;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

public class NonASCI extends EvalFunc<String> {
    public String exec(Tuple v) throws IOException{
        String val = (String)v.get(0);
        String non_asci = val.replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7e]", "");
        return non_asci;
    }

}
```

hope his will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but you can probably use a [regex that matches non-ASCII](http://dostmuhammad.com/blog/strip-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-using-regex-regular-expressions/#content) characters + the pig [REPLACE](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/func.html#replace) built-in function.

E.g.

```
stripped = foreach dirty_data generate REPLACE(dirty_data.string_field, '[^u0000-u007F]+', '');
```